# Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject when I am initializing it

Tags: apex, sobject

I am creating a Unit test for my class that uses two different object 
for some reason I cant get access 
This is the unit test

```
prequalAPI.QualifyLocationResponse qualResponse = new prequalAPI.QualifyLocationResponse();
         qualResponse.QualifyLocationId = 'ABC123';
         qualResponse.ValidAddresses = new List<prequalAPI.QualifyLocationValidAddress>();
         qualResponse.ValidAddresses.ProviderName.add('test');

///// PrequalClass

 public class QualifyLocationResponse {

        public String QualifyLocationId { get; set; }
        public List<QualifyLocationValidAddress>  ValidAddresses  { get; set; }
    }

 public class QualifyLocationValidAddress 
    {
        public string ProviderName {get;set;}

    }
```

this gives me the following error

> Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject:
>   List

List();
             qualResponse.ValidAddresses.ProviderName.add('test');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to set `ProviderName` on a `List<PrequalApi.QualifyLocationValidAddress>`, and the `List` class does not have any such member. Probably what you meant to do was add an instance of that wrapper class with that property set:

```
PrequalApi.QualifyLocationValidAddress validAddress =
    new PrequalApi. QualifyLocationValidAddress();
validAddress.providerName = 'Populated';

PrequalApi.QualifyLocationResponse response = new PrequalApi.QualifyLocationResponse();
response.qualifyLocationId = '...';
response.validAddresses = new List<PrequalApi.QualifyLocationValidAddress>
{
    validAddress
};
```

Or you could rewrite that last line as two if you prefer:

```
response.validAddresses = new List<PrequalApi.QualifyLocationValidAddress>();
response.add(validAddress);
```